# Circuitikz: How to draw an electromagnetic relay?

Tags: tikz-styles, circuitikz, circuits

How to draw an electromagnetic relay in `circuitikz` similar to the one in the figure?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try anything to draw this? If you started something and did not succeed, you should show your code here and precise where you got stuck. If you show some code, you'll help others to help you and you're more likely to find help.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp22513190107195968] 
\draw   (188,66) -- (301,66) -- (301,222) -- (188,222) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Inductor [id:dp24736203754521235] 
\draw   (206,243) -- (206,214.76) .. controls (206,208.27) and (210.48,203) .. (216,203) .. controls (221.52,203) and (226,208.27) .. (226,214.76) .. controls (226,208.27) and (230.48,203) .. (236,203) .. controls (241.52,203) and (246,208.27) .. (246,214.76) .. controls (246,208.27) and (250.48,203) .. (256,203) .. controls (261.52,203) and (266,208.27) .. (266,214.76) .. controls (266,208.27) and (270.48,203) .. (276,203) .. controls (281.52,203) and (286,208.27) .. (286,214.76) -- (286,243) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da051095141436859226] 
\draw    (156,109) -- (201,109) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp6778515719894689] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (192,109) .. controls (192,106.51) and (194.01,104.5) .. (196.5,104.5) .. controls (198.99,104.5) and (201,106.51) .. (201,109) .. controls (201,111.49) and (198.99,113.5) .. (196.5,113.5) .. controls (194.01,113.5) and (192,111.49) .. (192,109) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9500019856156845] 
\draw    (196.5,109) -- (288,92) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp44500646469446004] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (288,137) .. controls (288,134.51) and (290.01,132.5) .. (292.5,132.5) .. controls (294.99,132.5) and (297,134.51) .. (297,137) .. controls (297,139.49) and (294.99,141.5) .. (292.5,141.5) .. controls (290.01,141.5) and (288,139.49) .. (288,137) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp7250475164712205] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (288,91) .. controls (288,88.51) and (290.01,86.5) .. (292.5,86.5) .. controls (294.99,86.5) and (297,88.51) .. (297,91) .. controls (297,93.49) and (294.99,95.5) .. (292.5,95.5) .. controls (290.01,95.5) and (288,93.49) .. (288,91) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp8692741666377941] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (288,77) .. controls (288,74.51) and (290.01,72.5) .. (292.5,72.5) .. controls (294.99,72.5) and (297,74.51) .. (297,77) .. controls (297,79.49) and (294.99,81.5) .. (292.5,81.5) .. controls (290.01,81.5) and (288,79.49) .. (288,77) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da07997281760069219] 
\draw    (292.5,77) -- (337.5,77) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da847301105775671] 
\draw    (292.5,137) -- (337.5,137) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5564415966210661] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (246,105) -- (246,214.76) ;

% Text Node
\draw (148,88) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {C};
% Text Node
\draw (225,44) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Relay};
% Text Node
\draw (234,230.76) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Coil};
% Text Node
\draw (329,58) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {NC};
% Text Node
\draw (329,116) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {NO};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```